# php mysql selecting columns and compare with 3 values in different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 mysql tables holding interrelated data

- playersTable
- participationTable
- hotelsTable
- bookingsTable

I'm trying to retrieve the booking of players keeping in mind that some rooms might have 2 companions and some will not

MYSQL Tables physical design are structured at this way

**playersTable**

- playerID
- playerFullName
- playerCountryID

**participationTable**

- p_id
- championshipId
- playerId
- countryId
- status
- booking_status

**hotelsTable**

- hotelId
- hotelName
- championshipId

**bookings**

- b_ID
- player1_id
- player2_id
- hotelId
- arrivalTime

What I'm trying to do is `SELECT` all bookings and list them in a table where it can show both players, number 1 and number 2.

I'm using this query to get the results:

```
    SELECT bookingsTable.*, playersTable.*, participantsTable.*, hotelsTable.* 
    FROM bookingsTable 
    LEFT JOIN participationTable 
    ON bookings.player1_id= participants.p_id 
    LEFT JOIN playersTable ON participants.playerID = players.playerID 
    LEFT JOIN hotelsTable ON bookings.hotelId = hotels.hotelId
```

I'm only getting one player, so I added I added another query that chooses the `player2_id` but when looping through the results, I cannot get it to work correctly, but I can get the player2_id number and not the name.

This is my PHP code where it loads the results, a kind help is always appreciated.

```
<?php do { ?>
       <tr>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['id']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['playerFullname']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['playerFullname']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['hotelName']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['arrivalDate']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['arrivalTime']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['departureDate']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['departureTime']; ?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row_booking_retrival['Notes']; ?></td>
       </tr>
       <?php } while ($row_booking_retrival = mysql_fetch_assoc($booking_retrival)); ?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Find the physical design and intended results at this link.

http://s18.postimg.org/gjsx4frfd/example.jpg

Comment: How are you getting `$row_booking_retrival['player1Fullname']` as your column name is `playerFullName` and you are selecting the table data `playersTable.*` without an alias `player1Fullname`?

Comment: I dont have an alias for this, i just made it up for clarification, all im trying to get the data for both players in the same table after the query is succeeds. The other query is not efficient idea nor in implementation, it gives a wrong names, and the loop was made for only one query, so im thinking it could be a subquery or maybe a combination of both queries in one array? My mind is blocked and i cant think of any more improvement for this query nor a php statement to get the right results. Your help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data for the tables and then what your intended/expected output should be. For example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4bb47/3

Comment: You are too close to the correct result, however, I have attached an image of the current physical design to the question below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your table data and expected results in your image, your are looking for a query like

```
SELECT 
       b.b_id as BookingID,
       p1.fullname as player1full, 
       p2.fullname as player2full,
       h.hotelName as hotelname,
       b.arrival as arrivalDate
FROM 
       bookingsTable b
LEFT JOIN
       participationTable pT1 ON b.player1 = pT1.p_id
LEFT JOIN
       participationTable pT2 ON b.player2 = pT2.p_id
LEFT JOIN 
       playersTable p1 ON pT1.playerID = p1.playerID 
LEFT JOIN 
       playersTable p2 ON pT2.playerID = p2.playerID 
LEFT JOIN 
       hotelsTable h ON b.hotelid = h.hotelId
```

This then returns the results-
[image]

SQL Fiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68cd27/2

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked like a charm. Appreciate your kind help and consideration.